# Streaming CSV Download Missing Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-csv

In my Rails 3.2.x application I have followed the instructions in this blog post to successfully reimplement my CSV download to perform a streaming download as my prior method was timing out.

http://smsohan.com/blog/2013/05/09/genereating-and-streaming-potentially-large-csv-files-using-ruby-on-rails/

It mostly works, except the resulting CSV file is often missing the last several days or sometimes weeks of records.

Here is my controller...

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.csv { render_csv }
  end
end

def render_csv
  set_file_headers
  set_streaming_headers
  response.status = 200
  self.response_body = csv_lines
end

def set_file_headers
  file_name = "service_requests.csv"
  headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
  headers["Content-disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{file_name}\""
end


def set_streaming_headers
  headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'
  headers["Cache-Control"] ||= "no-cache"
  headers.delete("Content-Length")
end

def csv_lines
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    y << ServiceRequest.csv_header.to_s
    ServiceRequest.find_in_batches(500){ |transaction| y << transaction.to_csv_row.to_s }
  end
end
```

And the model:

```
def to_csv_row

 CSV::Row.new([],[
      created_at.to_s(:table_date),
      created_at.strftime('%A'),
      created_at.to_s(:time),
      user.name,
      user.email,
      ...
 end

def self.find_in_batches(batch_size, &block)
  includes(:service, :user, :salon, :appointment => { checkout: [], cancellation: [], no_show: [] }).find_each(batch_size: batch_size) do |transaction|
    yield transaction
  end
end
```

Note that I am only trying to download < 1000 records, but the complex joins was making the previous method time out.

Of course if I restore a copy of the prod database locally, it works perfectly. However trying to download from Heroku almost always results in an incomplete set of records.

Any help appreciated!